# Meaning of "as"

Tags: vocabulary, as

> Lawyers write **as** they see other lawyers write, and, influenced by
>   education, profession, economic constraints, and perceived
>   self-interest, they too often write badly.

What does "as" in this sentence means? I have two interpretations.

1. Lawyers write when they see other lawyers write.
2. Lawyers write like how other lawyers write.

Comment: It's the second (but *like how* is redundant: use one or the other, not both). +1 for the quotation! --what's the source?

Comment: If the second interpretation is correct, why does the sentence has "they see"? Shouldn't it be just "Lawyers write as other lawyers wite"? The source is one of the lsat prep test.

Comment: It's not quite the same thing: lawyers don't just write that way by coincidence, or perhaps because it's somehow built into the subject-matter, they write that way because ***they see*** other lawyers writing that way: they are imitating other lawyers.

Comment: The sentence sounds awkward to me, but I cannot explain clearly why it sounds wrong..Ill try to explain my confusing point as clearly as possible. First, because the verb phrase "they see" (which is an event) comes right after "as", it sounds like "as" is having a meaning of "when" in this sentence which leads me to think of the first interpretation that I mentioned. So my first confusion is, how can you make a judgement that first interpretation is wrong?

Comment: Secondly, assuming that my second interpretation is correct, I tried to replace the word "as" with "like". However, with "like", the sentence sounds awkward. "Lawyers write like they see other lawyers write". The phrase "they see" just sounds to be wrong for some reason.

Comment: In formal use *like* is deprecated there, but it's common in informal registers. You use *way*: Lawyers see other lawyers write that way, so they write that way themselves. → Lawyers write the way they see other lawyers write.

Comment: Ok now I can see what I am confusing. The sentence you suggested "Lawyers write the way they see other lawyers write" sounds like lawyers are writing in the way how they "observe" other lawyers writing. So grammatically it sounds like "the way" (or "as") modifies "the way how lawyers observe" other lawyers write, because the phrase "they see" comes right after "as". So it sounds like "lawyers are writing by using there method of observing other lawyers write" which sounds really weird.